# Getting duplicate data from csv file

Tags: python, json, csv

```
def general_number(request):
    csvfilename = 'algo/generalnumber.csv'
    csvfile = open(csvfilename, 'r')
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fieldnames = ("Ticker","Company","Industry","PreviousClose","Open","Bid","Ask","DaysRange","ftWeekRange","Volume","AvgVolume","MarketCap","Beta","PERatioTTM","EPSTTM","EarningsDate","ForwardDividendYield","ExDividendDate","OneyTargetEst","ticker_company")
    output = []
    for each in reader:
      row = {}
      for field in fieldnames:
        row[field] = each[field]
        output.append(row)
    return JsonResponse(output[20:30],safe=False)
```

Here I am getting duplicate data in json from csv.
Each datum is showing 10 times. What is wrong in this?

Comment: De-indent ```output.append(row)``` by two spaces

Comment: no. here it will give error if i will put indentation afetr row[field]

Answer (score 1):

It's just an indentation problem. Fixed it, try now!

```
def general_number(request):
    csvfilename = 'algo/generalnumber.csv'
    csvfile = open(csvfilename, 'r')
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fieldnames = ("Ticker","Company","Industry","PreviousClose","Open","Bid","Ask","DaysRange","ftWeekRange","Volume","AvgVolume","MarketCap","Beta","PERatioTTM","EPSTTM","EarningsDate","ForwardDividendYield","ExDividendDate","OneyTargetEst","ticker_company")
    output = []
    for each in reader:
      row = {}
      for field in fieldnames:
        row[field] = each[field]
      output.append(row)
    return JsonResponse(output[20:30],safe=False)
```